# SVG clipping in D3 brush doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: firefox, d3.js, svg

Using M. Bostock's example of [focus + context](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367), I'm trying to implement date selection via brushing: http://clflwd.org/lake-test.php.  It's working fine in Chrome and IE, but in Firefox the path overflows the chart during brushing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here --> [Insane CSS Clip Path Bug on Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768968/insane-css-clip-path-bug-on-firefox)

Basically, firefox thinks any clip-path style you set in a css file with a url#id is referring to an #id within that css stylesheet, rather than within your html document

If you add it as an inline style or attribute direct to the element it works.